# How to Load File Outside of, but Relative to, the JAR?

Tags: java, file, jar

I need to load a file outside of the JAR, but relative to it (`lib/config/config.ini` to be exact).  I used that exact path, and it works fine as long as the working directory is where the JAR is, i.e.

```
/path/to/jar$ java -jar JAR.jar
```

If it's run like this:

```
~$ java -jar /path/to/jar/JAR.jar
```

It can't find it.  How can I correctly load a file relative to the location of the JAR?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading a file relative to the executing jar file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627426/loading-a-file-relative-to-the-executing-jar-file)

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file

Comment: @iluxa: thanks, that works.  Strange that it's so hard to load a relative path...

Comment: @Sean: I couldn't get that one working.

Comment: "Strange that it's so hard to load a relative path..."  Oracle considers the path of the Jar to be **not the business** of the application itself.  Neither applets nor JWS apps. would have the slightest chance of finding the installation path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `getClassLoader().getResource("classname")` to find the URL of a class in your jar file. You'll find it's delimited with a `!` between the path to the jar, and the path within a jar, which you can easily slice.