# Load a file outside of a Jar

Tags: java

I have a folder called lib that contains all my Jar files and in one of the Jar files class, I have a main method which is called by a batch file. In the same folder location as my lib, I have another folder structure path/to/a/resource/myresource.txt

How can I load this file from a class inside the Jar file? I tried the following and both resulted in null:

```
getClass().getResource("path/to/a/resource/myresource.txt")
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("path/to/a/resource/myresource.txt")
```

Any ideas?  Even with an absolute path, it failed! Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `FileReader` to do so.

Comment: Have you updated the Class-Path entry in the jar's manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("path/to/a/resource/myresource.txt")
```

However, for this to work, you need to add the path '.' to the Class-Path entry of the JAR's MANIFEST.MF file.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

Answer (score 0):

Two things you tried are used to read files from class-path since this folder is not on your classpath you can read it directly with any of the java File IO classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File("C:/folder/myFile.txt");
```

or if you know the relative path:

```
 File file = new File("../../path/myFile.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your path seems not to be precise enough. Further, this question has been worked before.

Have a look here:

[How to Load File Outside of, but Relative to, the JAR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097789/how-to-load-file-outside-of-but-relative-to-the-jar)

[How to get the path of a running JAR file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file)

Answer (score 0):

You can either load the file from file system

```
new FileReader(relativeOrAbsoluteFilesystemLocation)
```

or you can add the directory in question to your classpath:

```
java -cp "lib/*;lib" ...
```

and then use your original method.

(Unix uses `:` rather than `;` as classpath separator)