# Java relative pathname from jar

Tags: java, jar, path

I developed a little program a while back, which I made into an executable jar-File.
It used some images I placed in a separate folder called "cache", which is always in the same directory as the .jar.

```
consoleBG = ImageIO.read(new File("./cache/consoleBG.png").toURI().toURL());
```

Back then it worked out of Netbeans and from the jar-file.

Now I have to come back to this project and suddenly the jar no longer uses a relative path:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Dromlius\.\cache\consoleBG.png
```

I tried everything and **the solution I found online:**

> MyClass.class.getResource("cache/consoleBG.png").toUri()

**results in a NullPointerException!**

I just need a quick and dirty way to get the relative path to the .jar-file, because the software will be used on many different systems.

Thank you in advance,

Dromlius

EDIT: Ok, when I call the jar from console like:
`C:\Users\Dromlius>java -jar X:\Dromlius\Projects\MyProgram.jar`
it does not work!
But if I navigate to the folder `X:\Dromlius\Projects` first, it works.i
I don't know why, but it is enough for my purpose.
I'm going to leave this question open for a bit though because someone might have similar problems and can not use this workaround.

Comment: did you try, MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("cache/consoleBG.png").toUri() ?

Comment: see another related question at SO, [How to Load File Outside of, but Relative to, the JAR?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097789/how-to-load-file-outside-of-but-relative-to-the-jar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ClassLoader.getSystemResource("cache/consoleBG.png").toURI()` and make sure that `.` (Current Directory) is in class-path

Comment: `ClassLoader.getSystemResource("cache/consoleBG.png")` returns null. What am I missing? the jar is in the same folder as my cache folder. And I checked spelling 1000 times!

Comment: You need to add current directory "." to your classpath