# Check if a file exists in the same directory as the jar file

Tags: java, file-io

I know how to check for a file in a specific directory or a specific directory but I can't figure out how to check for a file that is outside of the jar that is being run but in the same directory as it:
Test.jar - Ran -> Get location of Test.file
Test.file

Answered - Thank you!

This works great;

```
final Class<?> referenceClass = Client.class;
    final URL url = referenceClass.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
    try{
        final File jarPath = new File(url.toURI()).getParentFile();
        System.out.println(jarPath);
    } catch(final URISyntaxException e){
        // etc.
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `./myfile` path ?

Comment: Looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627426/loading-a-file-relative-to-the-executing-jar-file

Comment: You're right! I guess I just didn't word it correctly, it didn't show up when i was posting this. Though I've got my answer, thank you all for the help!

Comment: @user1782911 pls accept the answer which helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new file using the createNewFile() operation, get the location of that file and remove the file again.  The new file will be generated in the same location as where the jar file is running.

Comment: I think createNewFile() will create the file in current working directory of Java. Same, value can be read from `System.getProperty("user.dir");`

Comment: 'Where the JAR file is running' isn't the same thing as where the JAR file *is*.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is presented using `ProtectionDomain` in this thread: [Loading a file relative to the executing jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627426/loading-a-file-relative-to-the-executing-jar-file)

Answer (score 0):

The location of the JAR file is given by `Class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()` for any class that is known to be in that JAR file.